# why the data is not appearing in datagridview

Tags: vb.net

I have a form with 4 textboxes in VB.net for inserting Customer Info into a table. Now I want to show all data into DataGridView on the same form, the following code runs when clicking the "showall" button.

```
dtCustomer = retrieveFull("CustomerInfo")
    dgvCustomer.DataSource = dtCustomer
```

The retrieveFull function is as follows:

```
Public Function retrieveFull(ByVal tblName As String) As DataTable

    Try
        If dsSql.Tables.Contains(tblName) Then
            dsSql.Tables.Remove(tblName)
        End If

        cmdSql1.CommandText = "select * from " & tblName
        cmdSql1.Connection = Connect()
        daSql.SelectCommand = cmdSql1
        daSql.Fill(dsSql, tblName)

    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try

    Return dsSql.Tables(tblName)
End Function
```

**My question** is that when I press the "ShowAll" button so data is loaded into the DataGridView, all the cells are empty. When I click inside the cell then the text appears. Why it is like this? Why the data does not show directly? Kindly guide me.

Answer (score -1):

I think there is no method called like databind() in vb, databind() available in c#.

Comment: All functions are available in any language that compiles to IL.

Comment: Anyone who can take me out of this problem?